# Generating secondary menu based on node titles

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I would like to generate a secondary menu based on the first letter of all of my nodes that have a certain content-type, however I am unsure how to go about doing this.

Basically, I will be generating an alphabetical list of all nodes that I have (for a given content-type).

For instance, I would like to have my secondary menu generate A-Z, however only the letters with an associated node would be active.

So, if I had nodes: apple, grapes, mango, pear, then my menu would look like this:

**a** b c d e f **g** h i j k l **m** n o **p** q r s t u v w x y z

with the bolded letters being active links, and the rest disabled.

---

**edit**

ok, no responses in the past few days

how, instead, removing the 'secondary menu' requirement and simply generating a list of the first letters of all the nodes within a given content-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view containing all those nodes.  Then get the `custom-pager` module (also requires `token`), it should let you put together something.

You create a custom-pager.tpl.php in your templates folder, and you'd retrieve the list of nodes from the view.  I think it's called `$nav_array` but look at the custom-pager documentation.

You can then just sort nodes by their names and create your a-z list.  Will require a bit of PHP coding.

These might help...

http://drupal.org/node/114248

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/custom-paging-for-views